# Which authority regulates airliner design?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner

To which regulating authority's regulations and standards are large sub-sonic transport aircraft (passenger or cargo) designed? The FAA's, or EASA's, or both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safe operations of an aircraft is called [airworthiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airworthiness). It is the standard by which an aircraft is determined fit to fly. Responsibility of airworthiness lies with national aviation regulatory bodies, manufacturers, as well as owners and operators. International standards are dictated by [ICAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization) during the [aircraft design process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_design_process):

> The International Civil Aviation Organization sets international
>   standards and recommended practices for national authorities to base
>   their regulations on

FAA has [regulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Regulations) governing all aviation activities in the US. <strike>EASA also has airworthiness [regulations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Aviation_Safety_Agency#EASA_Part-M:_Continuing_Airworthiness).</strike>

The answer to your question is:

> The aircraft manufacturer makes sure that the aircraft meets existing
>   design standards, defines the operating limitations and maintenance
>   schedules and provides support and maintenance throughout the
>   operational life of the aircraft.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your link to 'regulations' take me to a regulation that governs maintenance for aircraft below 5700 kg used for non-commercial uses. Does this mean that larger aircraft are not governed by airworthiness regulations from EASA, but rather by ICAO recommended practices? It seems you are placing an emphasis on a difference between 'rules' and 'regulations', is this an accurate assessment?

Comment: Good catch. I didn't realize that the Wikipedia article had some missing/confusing information. A quick search about EASA's regulations for airworthiness didn't return anything useful. I will try to find some more information and will update my answer.

Comment: @Jonny Not quite. ICAO sets general standards, but does not set regulations or issue type certificates; that's done by national(-ish, for the EU) regulators. ICAO recommendations are to national authorities, but the national authorities actually _set_ the rules. The type certificate is issued by the authority where the manufacturer is based (in general, aviation authorities accept each other's type certificates).

Comment: @cpast: Indeed. However the individual authorities usually follow the ICAO recommendations quite closely. FAA probably differs most often.

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, the FAA regulates airworthiness. For transport category aircraft, such as Boeing and Airbus, the regulations are in [14 CFR Part 25](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5;node=14%3A1.0.1.3.11).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the EASA regulation is that governs transport category?

Comment: No, sorry I don't

Comment: I think it is [`CS-25 Amendment 10`](http://easa.europa.eu/document-library/certification-specifications/cs-25-amendment-15)